# "Storing" a user ID in an html page

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

i'm asking here cause i dind't found a solution to what i was thinking, hope  you all can help me. I'm learning html for make some view while i develope my spring boot projects, and i was thinking: can i store, until the logout, the id of a user (that is already in a db) in an html's tag and auto reference to that id  as query param/path variable when the user click on a link that is referencing to a post/get/put/delet method in my spring boot Controller? if yes, where and which tag i have to use?

Comment: You need to be concise in your question , like from code perspective what you want to do , what you have tried etc. As far as I understand, you can use Javascript to store the API result and then set the UserId value in any HTML display tag such as p, div, etc

Comment: sorry, honestly i didn't meant to use js for store the API result: i'm starting to use thymeleaf for display the result data from my controller to a table (for example). and i saw that i can pass those data as variable to fields in html tags. my question is: can i store/pass an UserID as variable in some place in the html page and reference to that id  when the user clicks on a link (in some part of the page) that is linked to a method in the controller? actually i didn't tried yet, i was thinking if was possible at first.

Comment: As far as storing is concerned, you can use, Html's sessionStorage and LocalStorage API , they are key and value based storage which can help you achieve your task, by the way, on front end i.e. client side, you have no other options other than JS,angular (Again JS type only) , JQuery to manipulate HTML tags and data

Comment: Just render it in a link, e.g. <a href="/something/12345">Do Something</a>

Comment: Or inside a form you can use a hidden field, which is then automatically contained as a POST or GET parameter on form submit.